# Angular 2 view not updating after I update a record in the database

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have a simple CRUD app using Angular 2. The main page displays a list of cards a user can create, edit, or delete.

On the card edit page, when I click submit, it calls this:

**card-edit.component.ts**

```
onSubmit() {
        this.updateCard(this.card);

        alert("Card updated!");        
        this._router.navigate(['/CardList']);
    }

updateCard(updatedCard: Card) {
        // call to card.service.ts
        this._cardService.updateCard(updatedCard)
            .subscribe(
            result => this.response = result,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
```

**card.service.ts**

```
updateCard(updatedCard: Card): Observable<string> {
        let body = JSON.stringify(updatedCard);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this._http.put(this._cardUrl + "/" + updatedCard.id, body, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

The card is updated in the database. Then the router takes me back to the list of cards.

**card-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core'
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/router'

import { Card } from './card'
import { CardService } from './card.service'
import { CardFilterPipe } from './card-filter.pipe'


@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/card/card-list.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    pipes: [CardFilterPipe]
})

export class CardListComponent implements OnInit {
    pageTitle: string = 'Card List';
    cards: Card[];
    errorMessage: string;
    listFilter: string;

    constructor(private _cardService: CardService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getCards();   
    }

    getCards() {
        this._cardService.getCards()
            .subscribe(
            result => this.cards = result,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }

}
```

**Issue:** The change I just made on the edit page is not reflected in list view. It takes a full page refresh to get the record to reflect the newest data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Looks like I have to call the router navigation in updateCard() instead of onSubmit().

```
updateCard(updatedCard: Card) {
        // call to service to update record in database
        this._cardService.updateCard(updatedCard)
            .subscribe(
            result => this.response = result,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
            () => this._router.navigate(['CardList'])
            );
}
```